# Error al hacer un makemigrations - Python Django Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

Quería ver si alguno puede ayudarme con este problema:

Tengo un error al querer importar una base de datos ya existente a un crud de django:

> valueerror: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Probé con varias bd, no tienen valores *null*, y esta mi IDE en *utf-8*, no se que puede ser, uso el comando:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > call\models.py
```

Comment: Te servirá algo de acá? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, hice lo de cambiar mi proyecto a utf 16, y luego lo volvi a utf 8 y se soluciono.

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, entonces :)